# Почему не работает this внутри then когда делаю запрос через axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Всем привет.
Есть такой код:

```
<script>
      import axios from 'axios';


    export default {

      data: function(){
        return{

          db2: [],

        }

      },

    mounted() {
        axios.get("http://seo-gmbh.eu/kurjer/tables.php")
          .then(function (response) {
            console.clear();
            this.db2 = response.data;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      },

    };
</script>
```

Вопрос:
Почему мне не удается засунуть response.data в переменную(св-во) "db2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы не используете стрелочные функции. В данном случае `this` ссылается на функцию, а не на объект vue.

Попробуйте переписать `mounted()` таким образом:

```
axios.get("http://seo-gmbh.eu/kurjer/tables.php")
          .then(response => {
            console.clear();
            this.db2 = response.data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          });
```

Comment: Здорово.
Работает.
А если мне необходимо генерировать елементы(HTML) из данных которые я получаю вышеописанным способом - то как лучше всего поступить?
если пробовать прямо вот как есть то у меня ошибка происходит.
Как я понимаю из за того что елементы уже пытаются генерится до того как данные из сервера получены.
Пробовал разные хуки жизненного цикла прописывать - ничего не помагает.

Comment: И еще вопрос:
Если я хочу данные получить сразу из нескольких страниц на сервере - то как это лучше всего сделать с точки зрения подхода?

Comment: По поводу элементов - очень расплывчато, зависит от компонентов, которые хотите делать. Но имея данные в data, вы уже можете их интерпретировать так, как вы хотите. Если это массив, то через тот же `v-for` их выводить и т.д., почитайте доки, очень хорошо же все описано

Comment: По поводу получения данных с нескольких страниц - просто несколько http запросов делать.

Comment: Пример который не работает:
Берем его и тот ответ, что вы уже скинули -  выдается ошибка.
_vm.db2.type_of_car is undefined


<ul class="ul_2_car_property">

        <li class="li_2" v-for="(value, key) in db2.type_of_car[0]">

          <div class="param">

            <span class="head">
              {{key}}
            </span>

            <span class="description">
              {{value}}
            </span>

          </div>
          <!--   <div class="param">   end   -->

        </li>

      </ul>
      <!--   <ul class="ul_2_car_property">   end  -->

Comment: Тоесть:
Если я напрямую работаю с этими данными(сам ложу их в DB2 прямо в коде)  то все работает норм.
(Элементы генерируются)
Если же я подключаю эти данные через запрос к серверу - то происходит вышеописанная ошибка..

Comment: Смотрите в сторону получаемых данных и их вывода. В ошибке написано, что в `db2` переменная `type_of_car` недоступна.

Comment: Так данные получаются нормально.
Это видно в тут:
http://joxi.ru/52aXbPzU4bZexm
db это то что я положил сам и с него генерируются елементы.
db2 это то что получено из сервера(тем способом что вы написали)
Из него генерироваться елементы не могут.
Но сами же данные идентичны - как еще в их сторону смотреть?

Comment: Попробуйте в `mounted()` положить `console.log(this.db2.type_of_car[0])`, что покажет?

Comment: Прописал вот так:
http://joxi.ru/zANMJPYsB6xyW2
Получил вот это:
http://joxi.ru/GrqlZnXCQkyx9A

Comment: А почему `db2` - string? Сделайте `db2: []` и попробуйте еще раз

Comment: и console.log нужно делать ведь после получения данных, а не до

Comment: Прописал вот так:
http://joxi.ru/E2p3KO1H9aV84m
Получил тоже самое:
http://joxi.ru/J2bxbPVcXGYvMr

Answer (score 1):

`this` это всегда объект, на котором вызывается метод. Передавая метод в `then`, вы его не вызываете! Метод будет храниться где-нибудь и вызывается оттуда позже. Если вы хотите сохранить это, вам нужно будет сделать это следующим образом:

```
.then(response => {
  console.clear();
  this.db2 = response.data;
})
```

Если вы используете версию ниже ES2015:

```
var that = this;


<тут запрос>.then(response => {
  console.clear();
  that.db2 = response.data;
})
```